# Is Apache Spark a right option for processing data directly from RDBMS?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, hadoop2, apache-spark-dataset, apache-spark-2.0

I Have completed one POC on how to interact with RDBMS [MySQL] directly using Apache Spark. I was able to interact with MySQL database from spark-shell using following code:

```
>>> empDF = spark.read.format("jdbc").option("url", "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/SPARKPOC").option("dbtable", "SPARKPOC.EMP").option("user", "myuser").option("password", "mypassword").option("driver", "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").load()

>>> empDF.printSchema()
root
 |-- EMPNO: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- ENAME: string (nullable = true)
 |-- JOB: string (nullable = true)
 |-- MANAGERID: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- SALARY: double (nullable = true)
 |-- PHONE: long (nullable = true)
 |-- DEPTNO: integer (nullable = true)

>>> empDF.show()
18/08/27 22:16:47 WARN SizeEstimator: Failed to check whether UseCompressedOops is set; assuming yes
+-----+----------+---------+---------+------+-----------+------+
|EMPNO|     ENAME|      JOB|MANAGERID|SALARY|      PHONE|DEPTNO|
+-----+----------+---------+---------+------+-----------+------+
| 7369|     SMITA|    CLERK|     7902| 800.0| 9567342250|    20|
| 7499|     ANKUR| SALESMAN|     7698|1600.0|95673422300|    30|
| 7521|     VIJAY| SALESMAN|     7698|1250.0|95673422500|    30|
| 7566|      AJAY|  MANAGER|     7839|2975.0|       null|    20|
```

Similarly I was also able to execute a query using Apache Spark and fetch the required results from MySQL.

I am searching for some more clarity on:

> Does spark reads the data in a single go from RDBMS, stores it in memory and then processes it?
>
> What if connection fails in between when Apache Spark is reading the data from MySQL? If at all some network connectivity fails in between does Spark starts the process from the beginning by itself or do I re-run the whole job?

Any quick references would be appreciated.

Regards,
Bhupesh

Comment: First: Too many questions in one, Second: primarly opinion-based, Sorry, it will be closed probably

Comment: Even I agree...

Answer (score 4):

Spark while reading the data from any rdbms create parallel connection to the server and the number of parallel sessions depend on the below parameters

numPartitions
PartitionColumn - it should be a numeric column
lowerBound
upperBound

data will be read from rdbms in parallel and at one go how many records will be fetched can be controlled by

fetchsize parameter

It’s always advisable push your respective query to the database and let the database handle the optimisation rather than giving the table name directly in the dbtable option.

If your connection failed it’s not required to rerun your job. Spark will retry the connection and read the data

Comment: Thanks for your quick and helpful respnce Chandan.

Comment: Please let me know if you need any help on the coding front. If this is helpful please accept the answer and consider upvoting

Comment: Thanks for your quick and helpful response. Could you please help me understanding your comment - "It’s always advisable push your respective query to the database and let the database handle the optimisation rather than giving the table name directly in the dbtable option." Is there any reference/link which you could provide where I could get more information in this regard? Also, how parallelism will be achieved if Spark pushes query to database?Will it get executed faster than processing that data with Spark[in memory within Spark cluster]?

Comment: though I don’t have any official documentation. What I meant is that while fetching the data from databases let the database optimise the query and give you the result and with that result you can keep it in a dataframe and do in memory processing using spark. If you have some complex query then better pass this to database itself